# SQL syntax for specific data located between - character

Tags: php, sql

I need to retrieve data from my database. I have column named DO in one of my table. example of the data in this column : 
BJ1-1-20140101,
MT1-9-20120401,
MT1-89-20130501,
M41-150-20130801,
MT1-1020-20140101

I want to get the number between - character.

so from above example, i want to get:
1,
9,
89,
150,
1020

i dont know the sql syntax to get the data.

Comment: I don't think SQL can do that.

Comment: if your SQL supports REGEX it is pretty easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works ...

```
select val,substring(val,locate('-',val)+1,locate('-',val,locate('-',val)+1)-locate('-',val)-1)
from test1
```

Far better way

```
SELECT val, SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( val,  '-', 2 ) ,  '-' , -1 ) 
FROM test1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
val              | RESULT
----------------- --------
BJ1-1-20140101     1
MT1-9-20120401     9
M41-150-20130801   150
```

Comment: this syntax works well, i also tried syntax from user3152121, but it does not work if the number increase to 4 digit numbers.. so this syntax from mhasan works really well..

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged PHP:

MySQL is not great for this kind of thing, as far as I'm aware, which is why there's so much fuss about normalising your database and all that. You'd be better off selecting the field in its entirity, then doing this in PHP:

```
list(,$thenumber,) = explode("-",$thedata,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine **SUBSTRING_INDEX** and **SUBSTRING**. Your query will be:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fieldname, '-', 2), 5) AS value FROM table
```